# Best practice approaches to ETL on Bigquery?

Tags: google-bigquery, etl

I'm wondering what some of the best practices/tools are people have found for building and managing ETL jobs on bigquery.

At the moment I have lots of sql 'templates' (horribly parameterized by lob, date etc using sed type string replacements into a tmp.sql file and then running that) and I use the command line tool to run sequences of them and send output to tables. It works fine but is getting a bit unwieldy. I still don't get why I can't run stored procedure type parameterized scripts on bigquery. Or even some sort of gui to build and manage pipelines.

I love bigquery but really feel like I'm either missing something very obvious here or its a real gap in the product (e.g. Pretty sure Apache Drill more built out in this regard).

So just wondering if anyone can share any best practice etl tips or approaches you use yourself.

I do also use xplenty for some jobs which is good but it's also a bit messy in that I can't just write sql in it so can be painful to build and debug complicated pipelines.

Was thinking about looking into Talend also, but really parameterized stored procedures, macros and SQL is all i'd ideally need.

Sorry if this is more of a discussion question then specific code. Happy to move it to reddit or something if more suited there.

Comment: Azure data factory is another good example. Would love something like this in Google cloud.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=164&q=label%3DFeature-Request

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/issues/detail?id=463&q=label%3DFeature-Request

Comment: I just mean that drill has create or replace ddl type commands and I'm assuming I could put a series of these in a single script and then use sql line to execute the whole script. So a bit more like a single stored procedure and that is my etl in one place so easier to manage and also break a job into lots of input tables if needed, whereas at the moment that's lots of separate files and logs. (this bit about multiple queries in one script is an assumption I'm making so I could be wrong here - going to download it to try this out when I can). I don't think I've explained this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cloud Dataflow is closer to your needs than BigQuery in my opinion. We use it for real-time streaming ETL with automatic scaling. Works great, though you will need to code Java.

Comment: Yeah have looked into that but don't know Java. I'm more coming from a data scientist background as opposed to software engineering so would take me a while to learn java which i cant afford at the moment as i need to quickly turn these etl pipelines around as business questions arise.

Comment: We now use Dataflow more and more, but we also use Pig scripts on Hadoop running in Google Cloud Compute Engine. We parameterise the Pig scripts with Python and orchestrate the jobs using Luigi (a tool from Spotify). Airflow is also a nice alternative to Luigy.

Comment: luigi looks very like what i'm after - thanks for sharing. any idea if there is BigQuery integration with it?

Comment: I'm looking into Apache oozie with bq command line tool shell scripts in case anyone else interested. Will update back here when get chance to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays a [dbt](https://www.getdbt.com/) project is the answer:

- define your SQL transformations (models) in a modular and versioned way (git).
- setup the [BigQuery adapter](https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/core/connect-data-platform/bigquery-setup)
- schedule their runs using [dbt Cloud](https://www.getdbt.com/product/dbt-cloud)